# How flexible is the Inquisitor spell repertoire?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am creating a new inquisitor character in Pathfinder. I'm a bit confused on how learning & preparing spells works.

In my character sheet, it says that my first-level inquisitor has the ability to learn four level-0 Orison Spells, and two level-1 Inquisitor spells. I can cast any number of level-0 Orisons per day, and I can cast three level-1 Inquisitor spells per day.

Because I am an inquisitor, I do not need to prepare spells before hand.

My question is this: Once I choose my four level-0 Orisons, and my two level-1 Inquisitor spells; am I able to swap out any of these spells with different spells from the list of Inquisitor spells?

For example, if I do not like one of my level-0 Orisons, am I able to 'swap' it out for a different level-0 Orison? If so, what are the rules for doing so? and when can this happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes

**Once I choose... inquisitor spells am I able to swap out any of these spells with different spells from the list of Inquisitor spells?** Yes, on a limited basis, starting at level 5.

> Upon reaching 5th level, and at every third inquisitor level thereafter (8th, 11th, and so on), an inquisitor can choose to learn a new spell in place of one she already knows. In effect, the inquisitor "loses" the old spell in exchange for the new one. The new spell's level must be the same as that of the spell being exchanged, and it must be at least one level lower than the highest-level inquisitor spell she can cast. The inquisitor may swap out only a single spell at any given level and must choose whether or not to swap the spell at the same time that she gains new spells known for the level.

[It's easy to miss, buried in a wall of text.](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/inquisitor#TOC-Spells)